# Deploying custom Nvidia program settings

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I would like to mass deploy Program Settings from the Nvidia control panel.  Our environment only has 1 type of video card.  We are also running windows 7 SP1 64bit

For Example.

Go to the Nvidia control panel > Manage 3D Settings > Program Settings

I would like to give a specific .exe AA options and distribute that setting to my user environment.  I do not want to use a Global Preset because this change should only be made for the specific Application.

Any insight would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the files I needed.
Copy the files from:

```
%ProgramData%\NVIDIA Corporation\Drs\*.bin
```

To target system.
Reboot the system afterwards